# Unable to link to VTK library

Tags: 12.04, cmake

The project I'm working on fails to link properly.  It is built with CMAKE.  It use to compile & link fine, before the PC got updated(Buntu11.04 to 12.04, installed packages updated as well).  The projects VTK is ver 5.8.0.

The err is: **undefined reference to QVTKWidget2::QVTKWidget(QWidget*, QGLWidget const*, QFlags)** This is a call to `VTK/GUISupport/Qt/QVTKWidget2.cxx`.  From here I'm lost.  I don't know which library is missing.  i.e. Which lib has the QVTKWidget2 class?  How do I find this?

I've tried `ldd VTK/build/bin/someLibs.so`, but all I'm finding are more `*.so` libs.  Is there a similar cmd that I can use to find out what is in the `someCompiled.a` files?

Answer (score 0):

```
ar -t someCompiled.a
```

Shows what is in the archive.